# Ccavenue Integration error 96

Tags: ccavenue

I am integrating ccavenue payment gateway in my project. While sending the request i am the getting the error code 96. I searched a lot about this, but couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same problem once. As far as i observed, this error caused by **wrong** or **missing** **Merchant ID**. Can you give me the name of Merchant ID field, so i would be able to help you out.

Regards.

Comment: what u said is correct. There was a problem in the merchant id. I corrected it. Thank you